# Save not leading zero in an integer variable

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I'm implementing the Huffman Algorithm in c++ so I need to write file in binary mode and I need to write to the output file "bits per bits" so I need to save the encoding of every character in a buffer and then print out that binary digit when the buffer reaches the length of a byte.

Here's the code:

```
char temp[1] = {toPrint[0]};
unsigned long long int binary_buffer = atoi(temp);
int bitscount = 1;
char buf[1];
for(unsigned int i=1;i < strlen(toPrint);i++)
{
    if(bitscount == 8)
    {
       buf[0] = (char)binary_buffer;
       fileout.write(buf,1);
       bitscount = 0;
       binary_buffer = 0;
       buf[0] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
       temp[0] = toPrint[i];
       binary_buffer = (binary_buffer << 1) | atoi(temp);
       bitscount++;
    }
}
```

So my problem is that the variable binary_buffer loses the not leading zero because it is an integer value so I lose a big amount of data. How can I save the not leading zero?
Obviously I can't use a char buffer beacause every char weighs 1 byte.

Example:

Text to encode: cccccvvv

Encoding table: c=0 v=1

Text to print out: 00000111

Text printed: 111

Comment: There are some serious flaws in the code you show, related to you treating non-string data as ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be very helpful if you would add the few additional lines that would make your code a [mcve] -- the surrounding `main()`, the include statements -- so we can copy, paste, and compile your example and see what you are seeing. This is _generally_ required for any "why is this not working as intended?" question.

Comment: You need to use a char array with 8+1 places. There is no other way around.

Comment: But i cant @hellow because every char uses 1 bytes

Comment: My comment was incorrect. I thought about a textual representation of a uint8_t, not a binary one.